# Python directory structure problem moving one directory up in the structure gives "no module named" error

Tags: python

This is my project structure in Visual Studio Code:

```
| database
 |- __init__.py
 |- database.py
| sales
 |- __init__.py
 |- shop.py
main.py
```

Insert database.py I have a function:

```
def insertArticle()
```

Now I want to use this function in shop.py so I do this:

```
import database.database as database

myResult is database.insertArticle()
```

This is one of the various options I tried but it all ends up with "No module named database"

I just run shop.py directly for testing purposes (so not from main.py)

Comment: Have you tried:
from . import database
And then use database.database?

Comment: Just tried it. Gives: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: Does `print(sys.path)` return correct path to your database module?

Comment: When I run this in shop.py I get ....\\testproject\\sales and in database.py I get ....\\testproject\\database